# Replicate JSF user input validation on business or persistence layer

Tags: validation, security, jsf

I have been working on a system that does user input validation only on the JSF Managed Beans. Theoretically, on the college bench, we are told to always replicate the validation on the business layer (or when it is not possible, on the persistence layer: through Bean Validation API or Hibernate Listeners).

However, after some research, I concluded that there is no security breach on that because JSF does not allow direct access to nothing "bellow" it. But I really want to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a security breach when you are only using JSF. In general I think it's best to have your validation and authorization as close to your data storage as possible. If you for example would decide to add a REST service to your application, your validation and authorization is already taken care of.

If you are using [`javax.validation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html), there is no need to replicate the validation in JSF when you are using a component library like PrimeFaces. In PrimeFaces you can simply use [bean validation](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/bean.xhtml) based on your `javax.validation` annotations.

Comment: Thanks Jasper ! In this case, it is a legacy system that already has JSF validation, and I am replicating it on model layer. My concern is some hacker could maybe bypass JSF Servlet and do some SQL Injection or use some other security vulnerability.

Comment: SQL injection could very well be possible when using JSF. It all depends on how well the other layers are written. If you simply append user input to a query string, JSF will only help so far (depending on your validation).